# Laravel displaying JS confirm dialog with another JS function inline

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Im using a bit of javascript inline so that i can display link text but have the link submit a form to a delete request.

Is it possible to display a javascript confirmation dialog before the form submit is called?

My code is as follows;

```
<a href="/deletestuff" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('delete-form').submit();" class="nav-link">Delete</a>
<form id="delete-form" action="/deletestuff" method="POST" style="display: none;">{{ csrf_field() }}{{ method_field('DELETE') }}</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog you are looking for is `confirm('are you sure?')` and yes this is possible to use inline.

A confirm dialog will return a boolean thus being able to use

```
<a href="/deletestuff" 
    onclick="if(confirm('are you sure?')){
        event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('delete-form').submit()
    };" class="nav-link">Delete</a>
```

Furthermore you could also use the `onsubmit` property of the form.
If you return true the form will be submitted, false will cancel the submission.

```
<form 
  id="delete-form" 
  action="/deletestuff" 
  method="POST" 
  style="display: none;"
  onsubmit="return confirm('are you sure?')">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `confirm` function on `onsubmit` event

```
<form onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');">
```